# What is the `settings.yml` file in Conan?

Tags: conan

I tried reading the documentation but it's not so clear what the goal of this file is. I understand that the *Profile* defines a set of settings (OS, arch, etc.) used by Conan when a specific client installs packages, but what is the functionality of this `settings.yml` file?

Comment: I had the same question after I ran into compiler versions that aren't included in the default settings.yml. "Why is conan checking my settings? Just do what I asked." It seems like settings.yml is just there to hassle, nag, and add yet another step to my Dockerfile file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well explained on [settings.yml](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/config_files/settings.yml.html) section, on Conan docs.

To summarize, `settings.yml` works like a template for Conan. Conan reads that file to validate which settings can be used. If you pass a `build_type` which is not listed in `settings.yml`, Conan will consider it invalid and raise an error.

It keeps a better pattern for all developers, you know everyone is using similar settings, no typo errors for instance. But you can [customize your settings](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/custom_settings.html), adding new features, like [new OS distro](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/custom_settings.html#adding-new-sub-settings).

But probably you will need to [share your settings](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/sharing_settings_and_config.html) with your cowokers, as now you have additional values, which is perfectly possible.

Regards.